# Select top nth row (or last row if there's fewer than n rows)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a numeric `score`, and I want to select the value of the 1000th highest score. Normally I would do

```
SELECT score FROM table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 999;
```

However, there may not be 1000 rows in the table yet. Of course I could `COUNT(*)` first, but is there another way? I want to get the 1000th row, or the last row if there are not yet 1000 rows.

Comment: What should happen if there are ties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select score
from (
    select score
    from table
    order by score desc
    limit 1000
) s
order by score
limit 1
```

Comment: Another nice effect is you can get an individual record ID with this (or other field on the record found) if need be.